# "be responsible" vs. "take responsibility"

Tags: grammaticality, difference

I want to say that I don't want to be judged for one's behaviour. So, are both of them correct?

> 1. I refuse to be responsible for your actions.
> 2. I refuse to take responsibility for your actions.

Comment: If you want to ask a new question, ask a new question. (Your edit seemed too far removed from this question, so the edit was rolled back.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are valid sentences and carry the meaning you intend. I would like to note though, that your question could be better expressed as:

"I want to say that I don't want to be judged for someone else's behaviour. So, are either of these correct?"

Comment: I've take your recomendation into consideratio. Thank you.